# grouping elements in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grouping

Is there a way to group elements in tkinter under single ID?

For example, if I want an 'S' with a line striking through it. Is there a way to store both the line and the character under the same id?

Alternatively, is there a way to create a costume (simple) shapes for tkinter?

**Edit:**
I wish to do this on a canvas widget

Comment: What type of widget do you intend to place the S with a strike through it on?  Is it in a Text widget?  a Canvas?

Comment: Canvas, sorry. I should have mentioned that. Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter [`Canvas`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) objects do allow you to create "simple" objects (anything you can draw using [canvas items](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#canvas-items).  Then you can group your objects together using [tags](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers).

Answer (score 2):

If you are specifically asking for text with an overstrike, you can create a [custom font](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm#fonts) that has the `overstrike` attribute set.

In a more general sense, you cannot have one id shared between two objects on the canvas, but you *can* have two objects share the same [tag](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#item-specifiers), and tags can be used just about anywhere an id can be used (ie: for changing colors, coordinates, deleting, etc)